# catkin only generates setup files every other build

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For some reason, `catkin build` does not always generate the various `setup.sh` files when I run it.

Running `catkin build` once, the contents of the `devel` directory is as follows:

```
cmake.lock  etc  include  lib  share
```

Running `catkin build` again:

```
cmake.lock  include           local_setup.sh   setup.sh        share
env.sh      lib               local_setup.zsh  _setup_util.py
etc         local_setup.bash  setup.bash       setup.zsh
```

Running `catkin build` yet again:

```
cmake.lock  etc  include  lib  share
```

Why is this happening?

I am using `catkin_tools 0.6.1` with ROS melodic.

#### Edit 2 (SSCCE)

1. Create and cd to an empty directory
2. `catkin config -s .`
3. `catkin build`
4. `ls devel`, observe that various setup files are created
5. `catkin build` again
6. `ls devel`, observe that setup files are gone

Running the following seems to solve the issue

1. `rm -r .catkin_tools`
2. `mkdir src`
3. `catkin build`
4. `ls devel`, observe that various setup files are created
5. `catkin build` again
6. `ls devel`, setup files are still present

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/356713/catkin-only-generates-setup-files-every-other-build/) by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1083 on 2020-07-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2020-07-09**:
What versions do you experience this with? Can you reproduce this on another system/workspace?

**Comment by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on 2020-07-12**:
@mgruhler This is happening on ros melodic, it's happening on multiple PCs and multiple workspaces

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2020-07-13**:
@Rufus I meant what versions of catkin-tools. run `apt-cache policy <PKG>` or `apt-cache madison <PKG>` for all relevant packages. Or specify the commit version if cloned from source.

I'm assuming you don't have any build errors when running `catkin build` and that everything is set up correctly.

As this is something very basic, I'm assuming it has something to do with your particular setup rather than with the package itself.  Would be interesting to see if you can reproduce this with an empty workspace and only extending `/opt/ros/melodic`....

If this is actually reproducible with a vanilla OS, vanilla ROS install, vanilla from-apt catkin-tools, you should probably file a bug on github (and link to/from this Q&A).

**Comment by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on 2020-07-13**:
@mgruhler i'm using `catkin_tools 0.6.1`.  There are no build errors.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2020-07-13**:
@Rufus, I cannot reproduce this. I guess you'd need to create an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) with which reproducing this is possible. If you can reproduce this over multiple machines and workspaces, you need to find the smallest common set of packages/whatever that leads to this.

Also, please confirm that this issue is also present with an empty workspace!

**Comment by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on 2020-07-13**:
@mgruhler The problem does not appear with a blank newly created workspace.

However, when I CATKIN_IGNORE all the packages in my workspace, the problem still occurs.  I updated the question with the output of the build when the problem occurs

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2020-07-13**:
Have you tried cleaning the workspace?

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2020-07-13**:
@Rufus good find. I can reproduce this now. Seems there is an issue if the config is generated in the source directory. This is something that could be expected behavior (i.e. the config should not be in the source directory). But with this find, I'd suggest you post this as a bug on github.

If I understand you correctly, you've fixed your issue by adding the `src` subdirectory. It might make sense to add this as an answer here and mark it as answered (or close the question). thank you.

**Comment by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on 2020-07-13**:
Issue created at https://github.com/catkin/catkin_tools/issues/621, thx for the assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems to be an issue with using catkin in a workspace without a `src` directory (i.e. configured with `catkin config -s`).  Issue reported at https://github.com/catkin/catkin_tools/issues/621

The workaround is to create the `src` directory and remove `.catkin_tool` so catkin uses its default configs (which expects packages to live inside the `src` directory)

---

Originally posted by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) with karma: 1083 on 2020-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0